# Change a list item's "Manage Copies" destination URL programmatically

Tags: powershell, splistitem

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script that goes through every item in a document library and updates the "Manage Copies" destination URL to a new location.

Is there any way to achieve this programmatically?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a list item's all Copy To -urls using Item.CopyDestinations.

You can then loop through the CopyDestinations and update each one. After you are done, call Item.Update() as normal.